# How to get mega menu with nested UL without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

We have the following html structure for our menu (see codepin). We would like to modify the menu without having to use JS on page load to move any elements around.

Here is what I tried, but cannot get the `custom-dropdown` to show like the screenshot below.

[Here is my codepin that I have so far](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/Oovvew), but we are having hard time getting it to align in two columns like the screenshot. The goals below have been simplified, but should be applicable to other links like `Category` and `Company` as well since they follow similar structure.

**Goal** (see screenshot):

1. On hover of Testing 1, `Collaboratively testing 1` and `transition accurate` should display
2. On hover of `Collaboratively testing 1` then the `Enthusiastically communicate cross-platform` and `Uniquely reconceptualize accurate` should display

**Screenshot**:

1. Underline below `Testing 1` is to simulate on hover effect
2. `Grey` background behind `Collaboratively Testing` is to indicate on hover effect, which results in goal #2 where they are display to the right.

[image: mega menu]

Answer (score 0):

**Multi-Level Drop Down Menu with Pure CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}
/* This hides the dropdowns */
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1bc2a2
}
ul li a:hover {border-bottom: 3px solid #2c3e50}
/* Display the dropdown */
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li { float: none; }
li:hover a { background: #1bc2a2; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
.main-navigation li ul li { border-top: 0; }
/* Displays second level dropdowns to the right of the first level dropdown */
ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
/* Simple clearfix */
ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}
ul:after { clear: both; }
```

here comes your html code

```
<h1>Multi-Level Drop Down Menu with Pure CSS</h1>
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Front End Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ajax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```